# Bind process error code-400 bad-request

Tags: iphone, xmpp, bad-request

I am trying to include jabber in my iOS application, for that i am using the XMPPFramework . I am able to authenticate successfully by following SASLAuthentication. Once i authenticate the next step performed is bind.

When i send the following xml for bind -

```
<iq type="set"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/></iq>
```

i get in response -

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" 
    to="abcd@xyz.com/f4f0t6c2m5ba4ed08c7621fd647e68932d602e91" 
    type="error">
  <bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind">
    <resource>f4f0t6c2m5ba4ed08c7621fd647e68932d602e91</resource>
  </bind>
  <error code="400" type="modify">
    <bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
  </error>
</iq>
```

the library again tries to send the same message and i get the same response from the server, with the cycle repeating indefinitely.
When i do the same for Google servers i get in response -

```
<iq type="result">
  <bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind">
    <jid>example@gmail.com/18AFA003</jid>
  </bind>
</iq>
```

where am i going wrong in my server?
i have set the proper server hostname and also port number.

i have tried introducing a delay just before the binding process starts but it didn't help.

Comment: Please double-check your question to ensure that the XML you thought you were including is visible.

Comment: I mean
XMPP framework forms an xml request and send. Binding request send <iq type="set"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/></iq> Response : <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><error code="400" type="modify"><bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
Thanks !

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: i'm using cisco server and authenticated successfully.